# Equivalent to im_func for __new__?

Tags: python, python-2.7, monkeypatching

I've got a chunk of code to automate monkey patching that caches away a function's im_func reference, and then replaces the function while attaching the im_func of the original as a ._unmonkeyed attribute, like so:

```
class MonkeyPatch(object):
    '''A callable object to implement the monkey patch.  Stores the previous version in
       attribute _unmonkeyed and new version in _monkeyed.'''
    def __init__(self,source,target,attr):
        self._monkeyPatchSource=source
        self._monkeyPatchTarget=target
        self._monkeyPatchAttr=attr
        self._monkeyed=getattr(source,attr).im_func
        self._unmonkeyed=getattr(target,attr,None)
        setattr(target,attr,self)

    ###a few more methods here

    def __get__(self,inst,cls=None):  #(self,*args,**kwds):
        tmp=lambda *args,**kwds: self._monkeyed(inst,*args,**kwds)
        tmp._unmonkeyed=lambda *args,**kwds: self._unmonkeyed(inst,*args,**kwds)
        return tmp
```

I'm not much of Pythonista, so I'm sure there's a thousand reasons this is a dumb way to do things, but it's worked for me.  Now I find myself in a place where I'd like to patch a class' `__new__` method to add some logic before calling the existing `__new__`.  `__new__` doesn't have an `im_func` attribute, and that probably indicates that there are other methods that don't.

Is there a way to accomplish the same job in a general way (preferably without having to keep a list of special cases) for methods without im_func?

Subclassing isn't the behavior I want here because I want to inject the new code into an existing class hierarchy.  This isn't production code, so I'm not too worried about the consequences of adding a few blue wires.

Comment: You need to look into the `type` object and metaclasses

Comment: `__new__` doesn't have an `im_func` because it's not an instance method.